# Multi-tenant Reporting Solution

Tags: mysql, symfony, web-applications, reporting, multi-tenant

We have a multitenant site where each clients data is partitioned by the equivalent of a customer_id.  We currently have a basic (custom) reporting system where we maintain a set of SQL queries with parameters that get replaced (based on the logged in user) to enforce the data separation.  While its not ideal it works for our current needs.

However, we are now having more and more sophisticated reporting requests including the ability for ad-hoc reporting.  Most off the shelf reporting tools assume you have the ability to expose the entire dataset.  We need the ability to restrict the data available to the tool to a specific customer.

For background our app is a Symfony2 application backed by MySQL and it would be nice to (relatively) easily embed the tool within the app.

Specific solutions/software are appreciated along with general approaches to multitenant reporting.

Comment: This is a tool request. As you know they close as such.

Comment: @Drew while I'd like to see someone suggest a tool that fits the bill, some basic google searches didn't turn up anything.  So I'd be more interested in how other people approach the problem in general.  I'd be happy to reword to make that more apparent.

Comment: There's http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ idk. I was just trying to make a point to a user here of 6 years.